# having issue with eclipse library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Droid development using Eclipse.  I am trying to use PinnedSectionListView found here: https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview

What I need to understand is how do I import that into my project? Do I need to load the project and create a .jar? I thought to use libraries like the one here it needed to be a .jar lib.  I am a bit confused on how to use github libs like that.  Also, not a big deal, I am fluent in c/c++/c#/objective c, but I am new to java.  Code I can handle, eclipse ide, jar files, etc. not so much.

Any steps would be helpful, or a pointer to an example. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the `library` folder! Then import it in your Eclipse from the `File` menu! After you have done this, you have to right click your project and reference the imported library as a `library project` in your original project!

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-in-android/

This is a link for another library but the steps are the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and unpack the zip file
2. In Eclipse's Package Explorer, right click and select "*Import...*"
   [image]
3. In the Import dialog, select "*Existing Android Code into Workspace*"
   [image]
4. Select the dir of the unpacked file, and click "*Finish*", the library is now part of your workspace, which leaves the last thing to do:
   [image]
5. Right click on your primary project and select "*Properties*", in the Properties dialog, select "*Android*" in the left panel, then click on "*Add*" button on the right side of the panel, select the library, click "*Ok*". Now you are ready to use its classes and resources.
   [image]